# How to hide the Notification Bar on the top of screen in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, notifications

How to hide the Notification Bar on the top of screen. I want to full the screen, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
Shell:SystemTray.IsVisiable="False" (Or true to display the tray)
Shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="Transparent"
```

You can refer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444218/hide-or-not-to-hide-the-system-tray-in-a-windows-phone-7-application)

Answer (score 1):

In the XAML of the page you're working on, you should find / edit this line:

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="true"
```

and set it to `false`

For more info about the customization of the bar refer to this:
https://nik.rolls.cc/2012/03/06/windows-phone-system-tray-tricks/